# How is the number of "views" counted in Hinduism.SE?

Tags: support, asking-questions, badges

Yesterday I asked following Qn:
[What is "Brahm" in "Brahmacharya"? How does it relate to celibacy?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20701/1049)

And just now I was notified for a badge due to 1000 views. However, I don't see so many people active in this site. To me it seems hardly 100 people will be active in a day.

How can a Qn garner 1000 views within 24 hours? Is the number of "views" counted differently or the site is popular more than expected. :-)

BTW, I have been in main StackOverflow for several years and there I have never seen view count reaching up so fast. It usually takes a week or more for an above average Qn.

---

Hot Network Question (HNQ-s) work like a charm. Following Qn got 1000+ views within 5 hours! To promote our site, we need more and more HNQs.
[Is there any god / deity for the mathematics?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20924/1049)

Comment: Question was on HNQ list. So, it got many views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when a new question gets considerble views, votes (and probably answers), it becomes [a hot question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot) within a community. Sometimes (based on the interest of users) such a hot question, raised to HNQ list i.e flashed on the [StackExchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com)!

This creates chances for a question to be viewed more and more. If such a hot & interesting question success in keeping the eyes of visitors, it remains on HNQ (Hot Network Question) list for enough time. And it can get unpredictable views!

Following post may be useful if you're interested in calculation algorithm:

- [How are questions in the 'hot' tab selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/260388)
- [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/260388).